# URL Key Priority for Pages from different Modules

Tags: url

I have a challenge where we have multiple modules + the core that builds URL Keys.  From time to time duplicate URLs are created.  Therefore I have been told there is a way to prioritise by module which URL Keys to use.

For example.  I have the Amasty Improved Navigation & Landing Pages modules.  On the improved navigation I have enabled the SEO urls.  I have an attribute called "Gloves", so this has automatically created the URL /gloves.html.  However I have decided that gloves is a strong keyword for us and I have built out the page /gloves.html using the Landing Pages module.  So the challenege is that by default magento is selecting the Improved Navigation page, where I would like it to select the Landing Pages page.

I have been told there is a way to create a config file to prioritise modules in this way, but cannot find any documenation on it.  Please can someone give some advise.